# FFMPEG merge mp4 file and mp3 file into mp4

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have video file in mp4 format (*video.mp4*), its length is 20 seconds. From 0 seconds to 10 seconds, the video has sound, and from 10 seconds to 20 seconds, there is no sound.

I also have mp3 file (*audio.mp3*) and has length 10 seconds.

I want to merge *video.mp4* and *audio.mp3* into *result.mp4*. The *result.mp4* file should have video stream and its audio stream from 01 second to 10 seconds as original and audio stream from 10 seconds to 20 seconds of *audio.mp3* as merged.

I use the command to merge:

> `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=10[s1];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[aout]" -c:v copy -map 0:v -map [aout] result.mp4`

But i get the *result.mp4* with video: there is no sound from 01-10 seconds, only new sound from 10-20 seconds.

It is the seem that my command don't keep the sound from original mp4 file, it has removed it and just keep the new sound.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=0:10[a0];[a0][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[aout]" -c:v copy -map 0:v -map [aout] result.mp4
```

Comment: Hi Mulvya, I got the error when run your command: [Parsed_trim_0 @ 00000252ced9efa0] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_trim
0' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_1' filter input pad 0 (au
io)
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000252d0a0c340] Cannot create the link trim:0 -> concat:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument